# Perforce trigger script not found

Tags: perforce, helix

I have a python script `trigger.py` stored in a depot at **//MyDepot/TriggerTest-main/trigger.py**. I want this to trigger whenever a user attempts to submit a changelist in **//MyOtherDepot**.

My trigger spec is as follows:

```
Triggers:
    block-all-changes change-submit //MyOtherDepot/... "py %//MyDepot/TriggerTest-main/trigger.py%"
```

I get the following error when I make a submit request from //MyDepot:

```
    Submit validation failed -- fix problems then use 'p4 submit -c 104762'.
    'block-all-changes' validation failed: 
    Execution Failed: py /tmp/tmp.8904.140611025375744.260.py: No such file or directory
    Submit aborted -- fix problems then use 'p4 submit -c 104762'.
```

Why is the script not being located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking py isn't in the PATH.

Hard code your path to rule that out:

```
block-all-changes change-submit //MyOtherDepot/... "/usr/bin/py %//MyDepot/TriggerTest-main/trigger.py%"
```

Comment: This gives the same error. I am thinking that this may have something to do with this line in the documentation: "Protections on the depot script file must be such that only trusted users can see or write the content." Not sure what this translates to in practice.

Comment: My mistake. The server did not have python installed, so installing fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Helix core trigger scripts need to be placed directly on the Helix core machine, not inside of a Depot path.

So if you instead put that file into a local path on the server, like /p4/triggers/trigger.py (I'm assuming a Linux server, so this path would be different on Windows) then update your p4 triggers table to

```
Triggers:
    block-all-changes change-submit //MyOtherDepot/... "python /p4/triggers/trigger.py %changelist%"
```

In this example, I have it passing the %changelist% argument as an example, even though you hadn't included that in yours.

This should be equivalent to running (using your changelist from above).

```
py /p4/triggers/trigger.py 104762
```

To test it, you can try running that command directly on the server to see if it works.

Comment: The documentation says that trigger scripts can be located in a depot. See "Storing triggers in the depot" at https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/scripting.triggers.basics.html#Storing